# Yii2 how to create a dataProvider dynamically

Tags: yii2, dataprovider

I have two models like below

```
$analytics=new CountryAnalytics();
$analytics->country="United Arab Emirates";
$analytics->totalAds=$uaeAds;
$analytics->totalUsers=$uaeUsers;

$analyticsKsa=new CountryAnalytics();
$analyticsKsa->country="United Arab Emirates";
$analyticsKsa->totalAds=$uaeAds;
$analyticsKsa->totalUsers=$uaeUsers;
```

$analtics and $analyticsKsa.These are building dynamically.So my concern is to add these models to an empty dataprovider like below

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider();

$dataProvider->setData($analytics);
$dataProvider->setData($analyticsKsa);
```

But it is not the right way.How can i achieve this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

For cases like this you want to use [`\yii\data\ArrayDataProvider`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider) instead of `\yii\data\ActiveDataProvider`

You can pass your models in array to the `allModels` property when creating its instance.

```php
$dataProvider = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => [
        $analytics,
        $analyticsKsa,
    ]
]);
```